# stack smashing in C code about making a histogram

Tags: stack, stack-smash

I need to make a c program that will make a histogram of all the letters present in a phrase the user gives. When I run it, I does it but gives a "*** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated". Where would this error be coming from? (for ease right now I set max to 3). In the future i'll have it find the max
Thank you 
Andrew

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
static void ReadText(int histo[26],int max) { 
   char phrase[100];
   int i;
   char Letter; 
   char toArray;
   // read in phrase 
   printf("Enter Phrase: "); // reads in phrase with spaces between words
   scanf("%[^\n]",phrase);
   // count the number of certain letters that occur 
   for(i = 0; i <= strlen(phrase);++i) {
      Letter = phrase[i];
      if(isalpha(Letter) != 0){ 
         Letter = tolower(Letter);
         toArray = Letter - 97; 
         histo[(int)toArray] = histo[(int)toArray] + 1;
      }
   }  
}

static void DrawHist(int histo[26], int max){ 
   int i;
   int j;
   int histo2[50];
   for(i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {
      histo2[i+i] = histo[i];
      if(i < 25) {
         histo2[i+i+1] = 0;
      }
   }
   // (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    //   printf("%d",histo2[i]);
    //}
    //printf("\n");
   for(i=max;i>0;--i) { 
      for(j=0;j<=51;++j) { 
         if((j < 51) && (histo2[j] >= i)) { 
            printf("|");
         }
         else if((j < 51) && (histo2[j] < i)){
            printf(" ");
         }
         else if(j == 51){
            printf("\n");
         }
      }
   }

    printf("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-\n");
    printf("A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z\n");
}

int main() {
   int histo[26] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
   int max = 3;
   //int i;
   ReadText(histo,max);
   //for(i = 0; i<26;++i) {  
   //   printf("%d",histo[i]);
   //}

   DrawHist(histo,max);
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You do this `int histo2[50];` and then `for(j=0;j<=51;++j) ... (histo2[j]` so when j=51 you still index the array.

Comment: You do this `int histo2[50];` and then `for(i = 0; i <= 26; i++) ... histo2[i+i] ...` so when i=26 you still index the array at 52.